# ¿Como crear archivos de forma rapida en NeoVim?

Tags: vim

Hace poco empece a usar NeoVim como editor principal, pero no logro encontrar una solución cómoda para crear archivos, estoy acostumbrado a usar "advanced new file", que con ctrl + n, solo pongo dir3 (Encuentra el directorio), y luego creo un archivo nuevo (O tambien puedo crear nuevos ficheros)

```
dir1
|__dir2
    |_dir3
|
|
|...
|
|__dirN
    |_ file (*)
```

Sin embargo me parece que en NeoVim no existe una herramienta similar, entonces ¿Como podria crear archivos dentro de NeoVim?

Answer (score 1):

Despues de buscar varias soluciones, encontre un nuevo repositorio con un plugin que es muy similiar a advanced new file,dejo el link por si a alguien mas le interesa.

https://github.com/SergioRibera/vim-files

Comment: Si usas un plugin como nerdtree o nvim-tree.lua puedes hacer click sobre el directorio donde quieres crear el archivo o directorio y apretar la tecla 'a' para agregar un nuevo nodo